# Qiime2 installation from pre built yaml file into conda environment doesnt work because of genomeinfodbdata package, how to fix?

Tags: anaconda, environment, qiime

When installing the newest qiime2 version (2022.8) into a conda environment with the given yaml file on the official qiime2 website. The installation gives an error which has something to do with the genomeinfodbdata package.

I tried updating my conda environment and using other genomeinfodbdata versions. But it didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Posted the question because it took some time testing and wanted to spare you guys the trouble. This was my fix. This problem happend on a linux distribution.

You should indeed also update the conda environment.

So in the give qiime2 .yml file on https://docs.qiime2.org/2022.8/install/native/#install-qiime-2-within-a-conda-environment there exist a package which gives trouble.
Go into the yml file and remove the following package/line from the file before making an conda environment of it:

- bioconductor-genomeinfodbdata=1.2.7

After making the environment you have to manually add the package with:
conda install -c bioconda bioconductor-genomeinfodbdata

This will install the same version but without the extra problems.